# Windows 8 Resource Hacking encrypted UIFILE's

Tags: windows-8, dll

In Windows 7 it was quite easy to modify resource files such as DLLs to make changes to the Windows interface. This was done by editing the UIFILE's using a program like Resource Hacker.

However, now in Windows 8 it seems like some of the UIFILE's are encrypted and are no longer in plain text form and editable in Resource Hacker like they were before.

Here's an example screenshot of what they look like now:

[image: Resource Hacker showing hex for a UIFILE]

I was hoping someone might be able to provide some insight into how I can decode this into the UIFILE XML and also compile it back into the DLL.

Comment: Not a marginal issue for you, is it? :)

Comment: Heh, yeah, still trying to figure out a solution to that. This is just step 1. =P